# Magento 2.4: Clicking on pagination in product listing page causes automatic scroll to the top issue

Tags: magento, magento2.4.4

I face an issue with pagination buttons. When a user clicks the button, the page automatically scrolls to the top on both mobile and desktop devices. To resolve this, we tried this solution but we couldn't disable the automatic scroll when clicking the pagination.

```
jQuery('a.page').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("Pagination class").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```